# Cancel/Dismiss input in ractive despite two way binding

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I am trying to use a  couple of `input` fields for data manipulation in ractive. In a simplified version it's basically:

```
new Ractive({
    el: '#myID',
    template: DataTpl,
    magic: true,
    modifyArrays: true,
    data: {myJSON},
    save: function (id) {
        //some code to save my Data to CouchDB
    }

const DataTpl = '{{#myJSON}}<input value="{{aValue}}">'+
'<button on-click="@this.save(_id)">Save</button>'+
'<button>Cancel</button>{{/myJSON}}';
```

Editing & saving works great, but the cancel button - which is meant to dismiss any user input cannot behave as expected. When I click on cancel, the binding already changed my `data`. So it is not stored to the database, but I cannot revert to the original value and therefore it is shown wrong in the UI until reload.

I also tried the `lazy: true`option, but that did not make any difference (I think because hitting the cancel button fires a `change`Event)...

Comment: mousedown instead of click?

Comment: Interesting idea, but that had the same result.

Comment: So do not use two way binding

Comment: That's always an option of course, but the two way binding is quite helpful for other parts of the script (such as fetching the actually changed data on my save event). So I was hoping any other idea that might pop up.

Answer (score 1):

> I also tried the `lazy: true` option, but that did not make any difference

[`lazy`](https://ractive.js.org/API/Initialization%20Options/#lazy) doesn't do what you think it does. By default (`false`), it updates the model on change. But if `true`, it updates the model when you unfocus the input. It's still doing two-way binding.

What you can do is set [`twoway`](https://ractive.js.org/API/Initialization%20Options/#twoway) to `false`. Then on clicking Save, call [`ractive.updateModel`](https://ractive.js.org/API/Instance%20Methods/#ractiveupdatemodel) to push up the data from the inputs to the model. This will update the model regardless of the `twoway` configuration. For Cancel, you don't have to do anything.

```js
new Ractive({
  el: 'body',
  twoway: false,
  template: `
    {{ message }}
    <input type="text" value="{{ message }}">
    <button type="button" on-click="@this.updateModel()">Save</button>
  `,
  data: {
    message: ''
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ractive/ractive.min.js"></script>
```

If you don't want to set `twoway: false` to everything, you can simply isolate this portion of the UI to a [component](https://ractive.js.org/Extend/Components/#using) and have `twoway` disabled for it while keeping the rest doing two-way binding. After all, that's how components work.

Alternatively, you can map the data to a keypath different from the one mapped to the UI. On save/cancel, you copy them over to the other. The approach is similar to how people do `angular.copy` in Angular, copying form data into the actual scope data when it passes validation.

Comment: Avoiding the cancel is not an option. In reality every row has an edit button, which sets all input fields of the corresponding row to `disabled = false` and shows the initially hidden save and cancel buttons. On hitting cancel I wanted any changes already made to the input fields to be dismissed, and the row reverted to its original state. So maybe I should try the second keypath for storing the original values and copying them back on cancel...

Comment: I've found not very elegant, but quite pragmatic workaround: If I attach `ractive.unrender();  ractive.render('#myID');`to the cancel button, the table gets redrawn from the unchanged data and any user input is reverted.

Comment: @Torf Yep. I withheld that option when I edited and added the copy option. :D